# Reusing a MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, email

I have an app that is built on the TabBar-based app in which I need to have one tab that is basically an email composer.  So I'm trying to use a MFMailComposeViewController as one of the tabs.  This seems to work fine until I actually go to send an email with the controller.  If I do this the MFMailComposeViewController's view disappears and can't be used again.

If I'm reading the docs correctly, the MFMailComposeViewController is normally used modally, but it is supposed to work non-modally as well.

This is how I am adding it to the tab bar...

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailController.title = @"Feedback";
mailController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pencil.png"];
[array addObject:mailController];
tabBarController.viewControllers = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You you using

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

and hides it with

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If so then just comment dismissing.